# How to get PoS tag of individual words in a sentence?

Tags: java, nlp

I have been using [Stanford POS Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) to tag parts of speech in a sentence. What I have learnt from the documentation and other questions on the topic on stackoverflow is that following code gives POS Tagging of a sentence

```
            MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("./left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");
                     String tags=tagger.tagString(Summary);
```

but what I want is to get the POS Tag of individual words. One possible way of doing this is to break up the input string and give input to the Tagger word by word but it does not seem elegant and I think that it increases the chances of errors. [Javadoc](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html#apply%28java.util.List%29) says that apply function is available that returns the ArrayList of TaggedWords but I have not been able to call this function successfully.
Any idea how can I get the POS tagging of individual words of a string using Stanford POS 
Tagger either by apply function or some other function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should use tokenizeText() together with tagSentence() to get a list of tagged words.  Check out TaggerDemo.java included in the postagger distribution.